# Sweet Alert Delete Just Working in the Last Data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, sweetalert

First, im sorry if my english so bad :v
I have a problem, i have many data, and i want to delete some data with sweet alert delete confirmation, but this delete confirmation just working in the last data (last row), if i want to delete data in first row or middle, thats sweet alert its not working, but my data still deleted, i hope someone wanna help me, thanks

i use codeigniter and this ss of my code

This part of code

```
<tbody>
              <?php foreach ($karyawan as $karyawan): ?>
                <tr>

                  <td>
                    <?php echo $karyawan->IDKaryawan; ?>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <?php echo $karyawan->NamaKary; ?>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <?php echo $karyawan->NoHp; ?>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <?php echo $karyawan->alamat; ?>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <?php echo $karyawan->tanggalmasuk; ?>
                  </td>
                  <td>

                      <a href="<?php echo site_url('karyawan/detailkaryawan.php?id='.$karyawan->IDKaryawan); ?>" title="Detail Karyawan"><img width="24" height="24" src="<?php echo base_url('img/detail.png'); ?>" /></a>
                        <a href="<?php echo site_url('karyawan/editkaryawan?id='.$karyawan->IDKaryawan); ?>" title="Edit Karyawan"><img width="20" height="20" src="<?php echo base_url('img/edit.png'); ?>"/></a>
                      <a href="<?php echo site_url('karyawan/hapuskaryawan/'.$karyawan->IDKaryawan); ?>" id="sa-params" title="Hapus Karyawan"><img width="20" height="20" src="<?php echo base_url('img/hapus.png'); ?>" /></a>

                  </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
```

and this my js

```
  $('#sa-params').on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var abc = $(this).attr('href');
    swal({
        title: "Anda Yakin?",
        text: "Data Yang Sudah Terhapus Tidak Bisa Dikembalikan Lagi!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Ya, Hapus!",
        cancelButtonText: "Jangan Hapus!",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
    }, function(isConfirm){
        if (isConfirm) {
            swal("Terhapus!", "Data Berhasil Dihapus.", "success");
            setTimeout(function(){ window.location.replace = abc; }, 2000);
        } else {
            swal("Cancelled", "Data Tidak Jadi Dihapus :)", "error");
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably happend, because you are using id instead of class in your link.

Change `id="sa-params"` to `class="sa-params"` in your anchor and

```
$('#sa-params').on("click", function(e){
    //your code
});
```

to

```
$('.sa-params').on("click", function(e){
    //your code
});
```

in javascript